Which Python or SQL Alchemy datatype should be used to store the Python `bytes` datatype as a fixed width field?
I want to store some data into a SQL database. (In this case, Postgres, however this may not be relevant.)
Some of the columns I want to store contain binary data. The Python datatype is bytes.
What datatype should I use to specify the bytes datatype with SQL Alchemy? (With the additional constraint that the column be of fixed width.)
For the str datatype, Mapped[str] can be used.
If the width should be of fixed rather than unconstrained length, Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(<length>)) can be used. Here is an example:
class HtmlData(MyBase):
    __tablename__ = 'html_data_table_name'

    html_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    html_div_md5: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(16))

For binary data, the bytes datatype will work. However this is of unconstrained width.
How can I specify a fixed width for the bytes datatype?
While researching this question I found the LargeBinary SQL Alchemy datatype. This seems like it might be the right thing to use. However, if the length is restricted to a small value such as 16 bytes, is this still the appropriate datatype?

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.LargeBinary


It turns out this isn't possible.
LargeBinary maps to bytea in Postgres. This does not have a length parameter, and the data cannot be configured to be of a fixed length.
